# SQL sentence for Cumulative Count un Grafana

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, grafana, cumulative-sum

I have a PostgreSQL database connected to a Grafana dashboard. I’d like to make a cumulative count and show it in a graph, but I haven’t found the way to achieve it. Concretely, my table looks like this:

```
project_name / project_namespace / project_creation_date
Project A / Namespace A / 2019-05-22
Project B / Namespace B / 2019-05-23
Project A2 / Namespace A / 2019-05-23
Project C / Namespace C / 2019-05-23
Project D / Namespace D / 2019-05-24
Project B2 / Namespace B / 2019-05-24
```

What I’d like to show in my graph is, for each date, the number of namespaces existing. For May 22nd there is one namespace (A), for May 23rd there are two new namespaces (B and C), and for May 24th a new one (D). This way, the cumulative evolution of namespaces is this:

```
2019-05-22 Number of namespaces: 1 (A)
2019-05-23 Number of namespaces: 3 (A, that already existed, and new B and C)
2019-05-24 Number of namespaces: 4 (A, B and C, that already existed, and D)
```

This way, the graph should mark 1 in 22nd, 3 in 23rd and 4 in 24th. How could I achieve this with a SQL sentence in Grafana?

Very grateful for your help,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to get the first date for each name_space.  In Postgres, you can express this as:

```
select project_creation_date, count(*) as day_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by project_creation_date) as cumulative_count
from (select distinct on (project_namespace) project_namespace project_creation_date
      from t
      order by project_namespace, project_creation_date
     ) t
group by project_creation_date
order by project_creation_date;
```

The below is equivalent (and standard SQL) but may not perform quite as well:

```
select project_creation_date, count(*) as day_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by project_creation_date) as cumulative_count
from (select project_namespace, min(project_creation_date) as project_creation_date
      from t
      order by project_namespace, project_creation_date
     ) t
group by project_creation_date
order by project_creation_date;
```